# UWP TabView scroll button

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app

[image: TabView]

I find out that the tabs of `TabView` can be scrolled when there is an overflow. And I can scroll them using the buttons I circled out in the image I posted above.

However, I can't find out how to modify them. I just want to set their `BorderThickness` to 0. Can someone point them out in the [source style](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/Dictionaries/PlaylistTabView.xaml) of my `TabView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RepeatButton in your PlaylistTabView.xaml represents the style of the Button which you circled out, so you can set the BorderThickness to 0 in it. Note that there are two RepeatButtons in your xaml, so you need to set them both.

PlaylistTabView.xaml:

```
<RepeatButton
                 x:Name="ScrollBackButton"
                 VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                 Background="Transparent"
                 BorderThickness="0"
                 Delay="50"
                 FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                Interval="100"
                Style="{StaticResource RepeatButtonRevealStyle}"
                Visibility="{Binding ScrollableWidth, Converter={StaticResource GreaterThanToleranceVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, FallbackValue=Collapsed, TargetNullValue=Collapsed}">
                                &#xE76B;
</RepeatButton>
```

Comment: Ah, it is in the `ScrollViewer`. No wonder I couldn't find it...