# UWP TabView RepeatButton

Tags: c#, uwp, tabview, repeatbutton

I have a problem with a RepeatButton in a TabView, I don't know how to resize it so that they are in height as adjacent elements

[image]

```
<controls:TabView 
        Width="400"
        AddTabButtonClick="TabView_AddTabButtonClick" 
        TabCloseRequested="TabView_TabCloseRequested" 
        Loaded="TabView_Loaded">

        <controls:TabView.TabItems>
            <controls:TabViewItem Header="Something" Height="50"/>

            <controls:TabViewItem Header="Something"/>

            <controls:TabViewItem Header="Something"/>

            <controls:TabViewItem Header="Something"/>

            <controls:TabViewItem Header="Something"/>

            <controls:TabViewItem Header="Something"/>

            <controls:TabViewItem Header="Something"/>

            <controls:TabViewItem Header="Something"/>
            <controls:TabViewItem Header="Something"/>

        </controls:TabView.TabItems>
```

I found a similar problem, but I still don't understand how to solve [UWP TabView scroll button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58469841/uwp-tabview-scroll-button)

How can I set RepeatButton sizes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set the `Height` of the `RepeatButton` of `TabView`, you could do it in a style of `TabView`. Open the style [document](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/master/dev/TabView/TabView.xaml) of `TabView`, you could see the two RepeatButtons are in the `Style` named [TabScrollViewerStyle](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/master/dev/TabView/TabView.xaml#L186).

Please check the follow steps:

1. Open the **Document Outline** panel, right-click your `TabView` and select **Edit Template > Edit a Copy**. Then your `TabView` will apply the copied style automatically.
2. Copy the code from [line 99](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/master/dev/TabView/TabView.xaml#L99) to [line 229](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/master/dev/TabView/TabView.xaml#L229) below the copied style.
3. Copy the necessary xmlns(contract4Present, primitives, contract7NotPresent, contract7Present, primitiveContract7Present and so on) of [ResourceDictionary](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/master/dev/TabView/TabView.xaml#L5) into the `Page` element of your xaml file
4. Find the two RepeatButtons and set the value of `Height` property as 50.
5. Build your project.